Play Console | App Access | Login with restricted oauth provider | How to provide test credentials
The app has login only and only with UAE PASS oauth provider.
I am preparing the app for the review, and for that I need test credentials.
There doesn't seem to be a way to create dummy / test account on UAE PASS ( which makes sense BTW )
I wanted to submit the app for the review, but I couldn't figure out how to give test credentials for login. Is there any workaround?
